# how to create resizable and dragable popup in wpf?

Tags: wpf, popup

i can create a popup with usercontrol. and works fine. when i have to resize or drag it. i cant able to move in window. and how to open multiple popup with below code?

```
<Popup Placement="Center" Name="chatpop" StaysOpen="False">
        <Border Background="White">
    <vm:User x:Name="User" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <vm:User.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </vm:User.RenderTransform>
    </vm:User>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ScatterViewItem` to achieve your popup drag and resize. Please have a look at this link for more details.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/135097/Custom-Sized-ScatterViewItems

Comment: This is not useful answer and does not make any sense!!